# To view a result of mathematical action

Tags: android

I'd like to show the text containing result of addition of two values: one from onespinner selected item, and another from twospinner selected item. But eclipse shows an error in line

```
text.setText(onespinner.getSelectedItem + twospinner.getSelectedItem);
```

What's the matter? Full code goes below.

```
public class photographer extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner onespinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> unitadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.onespinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    unitadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    onespinner.setAdapter(unitadapter);
    onespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner twospinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> courseadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.twospinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    courseadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    twospinner.setAdapter(courseadapter);
    twospinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    text.setText(onespinner.getSelectedItem + twospinner.getSelectedItem);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the exact error, but I'm guessing that your problem is that you are trying to make a reference to `onespinner` and `twospinner` in `onItemSelected` and those two objects are not in the scope of that function; they are declared in `onCreate`.

Now, the `View view` argument of `onItemSelected` is the spinner that was clicked, but you need a reference to both spinners (not just the one that was selected). Easiest way to do this is to globally declare `oneSpinner` and `twoSpinner` and that should solve your problem.

EDIT: Also what Ted Hopp said.

Answer (score 1):

`getSelectedItem` is a method, but you are referencing it like an instance variable. You need to change your code to:

```
text.setText(onespinner.getSelectedItem() + twospinner.getSelectedItem());
```